# Dependency Property and Notifying Child Control

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have a Parent Control, which has a dependency property.

```
public class BaseControl:UserControl
{
    public MyObject SpecialObject
    {
        get { return (MyObject)GetValue(SpecialObjectProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SpecialObjectProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SpecialObjectProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SpecialObject", typeof(MyObject), typeof(BaseControl), new PropertyMetadata(default));
}
```

Later, I am creating multiple child properties based on this parent `BaseControl`. I was wondering what would be the best way to notify my child controls when `SpecialObject` Property changes.

Furthermore, can I do this from `ViewModel` of Child Control instead of Code behind.
Sorry am pretty new to `WPF`

Comment: Can you explain what you are using this for? Maybe then it's easier to understand what you want to do and how to put this in line with MVVM using WPF

Comment: I'd suggest go with VM-VMChild approach.

Comment: Hi,  I have this set of controls which are supposed to have a common depedency property. So i created a base control from which other controls are inherited. The other parts (UI Elements) of Child Control are filled based on this very Depedency Property's value.